# Bulk Download App 'Insuficient Previledges'

Tags: remote-sensing, usgs, landsat-7

Ordered Landsat 7 data from USGS and wants to download it using the Bulk Download application. However, i get this error while running the software.
[image: Error Image]
I have JRE Installed properly. 
Does someone knows how to got about this Insufficient error problem.

Comment: What directory is the bulk download application installed in? There should be a file named config.xml in that directory. I get this error when I remove that file.

Comment: Looks like you may need to download and install this using an administrator account?

Comment: Running the program as administrator once should rebuild the file and keep you from getting this error in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are other options to download Landsat7 images. Here's what I do:

- Go to [EarthExplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) and click on `register` on the upper right
  corner to create an account.
- Then again go to `EarthExplorer` and log in with the account that
  you have just created.
- In the first tab `Search Criteria`, you can set the acqusition time
  and area of the data by different option. For example I have done
  this by searching the name of a place. But if you now the `path` and
  `row` of the scene, you can use that.
- In the second tab `Data Sets`, you can specify that you are searching
  for the data acquired by `Landsat7 ETM+`
- In the third tab `additional criteria`, you can specify some
  characteristics like `cloud cover`, etc.
  Then in the 4th and last tab, you can choose one of the data and check it to see if it contains your search area by the `footprint` icon. Then if you click on the icon that I have marked by red, you will have access to download options. And here I can download the data by just clicking on the download button next to `Level 1 Product` using `IDM` that is integrated with my firefox or any other way of download that is suitable for you.

[image]

P.S. I myself had problems with the bulk downloader and I found that this way is better.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer seems to point to the alternatives of downloading the images. The **bulk download application** is the main issue and whether someone has success in bypassing that error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when installing to the default location Program Files. 
I uninstalled the first attempt, and reinstalled to a custom folder on my drive (C:\LaptopSoftware\USGS_EROS\AppInstall).

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue and it is resolved by changing the directory. So, change your file directory to Driver Volume /D (if you have a partition of driver in your PC)

Answer (score 1):

You should run bda.exe as admnistrator. Furthermore, its a good thing to install it outside the 'program files' folder.

Now I encountered a problem with high CPU usage, bda.exe was using 100% of CPU.  But i found a way to limit the number of processors for it to use:
(Task manager -> Details -> right click on bda.exe -> affinity -> let just 2 or 3 processors for bda, it's more than enough), it worked well.

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stackechange. I have edited out your follow up question "Does anyone know how to download the full list in sequence, automatically?" - If you take the Tour https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour you will get the idea, this is a focused questions and answers site rather than a forum. If you have separate question it is best to post it as a new question and ask for an answer that way.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem - easily resolved by changing the default installation folder from "Program Files" to (in my case) the main C drive.